# .Net C# Can't get Japanese Kanji (only the unicode values) when crawling web links

Tags: c#, winforms, character-encoding, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

### This is a WinForms app:

I have not found a solution that works for me yet, although people do have similar problems to this on SO.

I have the following code:

```
private static ArrayList GetURLS(string url)
        {
            ArrayList alLinks = new ArrayList();

            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);

            var linkTags = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("link");
            var linkedPages = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
                                              .Select(a => a.GetAttributeValue("href", null))
                                              .Where(u => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(u))
                                              .Where(u => !u.StartsWith("#")); // Don't include empty links and those that start with a #

            foreach (string links in linkedPages)
            {
                if (IsValidUri(links))
                {
                    if (!alLinks.Contains(links)) alLinks.Add(links.ToLower());
                }
            }

            return alLinks;
        }
```

The web crawler - goes everywhere, and it just fouls up as soon as it hits a Non-English site. Instead of (in a Japanese page) getting the url as Kanji/Hiragana etc it returns the %3e unicode type encodings. Which is fine in that we can crawl those too.

However, the end user is faced with horrific looking urls!

**So, to the question:**

1. How can using a modification of the code provided get the properly encoded links during the crawl?

Comment: Does [`HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) solve your problem?

Comment: Might do if it was asp.net. Sorry should have said it is WinForms

Comment: Ah. In that case, check [`HttpUtility.UrlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Not sure why this method essentially exists twice.

Comment: @KonradRudolph make that an answer and you have yourself some points! Got it working thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `System.Web.HttpUtility` has a method [`UrlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to accomplish this:

```
var decoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(links.ToLower());
alLinks.Add(decoded);
```

Example:

```
var url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97";
Console.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url));
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/漢字
```

Comment: Very helpful and instructive.